# Why does shot noise becomes 'non-shot' beyond a certain threshold?

Tags: noise

My understanding of shot noise is that if a process is Poissonian, the noise observed is 'shot noise' and its total variance will go hand in hand with the mean value of the noise. But, judging from the Wikipedia page on [shot noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise) and a few scientific papers, when systems go above the 'Poissonian' level (for example, when there are a lot more photons hitting a detector) then this property is not true anymore. Instead, the mean value of the noise appears to scale with its standard deviation. Why is this the case?